# Delete/update laravel pivot table entry by id

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table

I've got a database structure as follows where item A is in a many to many relationship with B.

This is a true many to many, so:

Item X (object in table A) relates to Y (object in B) multiple times.

Using the laravel `attach()` function easily adds these records. However, I need to update and delete these items.

The `detach()` and `sync()` methods seem to not be appropriate. They assume only one pivot table entry between one record and another record.

If I `detach()` then ALL items are deleted. That is not what I want.

So the main point of my question:

If I have the id of the pivot table record, how do I delete/update it... *given that* detach doesn't work as expected.

Or put another way:

How can I interact with a pivot table object directly?

Comment: Create a model for pivot table and go for it. But I think there is a better way to do that,

Comment: Pivot tables extend `Pivot` so they're not the same as a normal model, so that's a no go.

Comment: Laravel is not very good with dealing with this scenario. Perhaps it's not unreasonable your pivot be made its own model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all,

@devk has pointed out a good solution to the problem if you have the child objects available. I've upvoted this answer because it is true and useful for future reference.

Unfortunately, at this particular point I only have the many-to-many id, so i am answering this with a "No - there is no specific way to access the pivot table by id" using the `Pivot` or similar objects.

However: to be clear, this can still be done in eloquent using the DB class.

```
        DB::table('many-to-many-lookup')
          ->where('id', $id)
          ->take(1)
          ->delete();
```

Comment: You could just make a `Model` for your pivot table. It's usually not the encouraged way, since pivots don't usually have an `id` column, but a composite key - which Laravel's `Model` doesn't support. But since you do have an `id` you could just make a `Model` for the pivot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`newPivotQuery()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.php#L433).

Something like that:

`Parent::relation()->newPivotQuery()->where('id', $someId)->delete();`

The `where()` and `delete()` statements will apply to the pivot query.